# Design database table to check id in another table before allowing insert

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've got what I'm sure is a really simple database question, but  I don't even know what to google, so hopefully someone can help me here.

I'm trying to create 2 tables that are interconnected. For example, lets say I have an employee table with employee name and employee id, then I'm creating another table, employee_bonus, with employee id and bonus amount. What I want is for the employee_bonus table to automatically check with the employee table every time a row is inserted to make sure that the employee id exists in the employee table and reject the insert if not. The thing is, there could be multiple bonuses for a single employee, so I just want it to check that it exists, not make it one to one. Does that make sense? Is that possible? How would I do that and WHAT is that called?

Also, I'm doing this in MySql.

Comment: You want to google foreign keys or referential integrity constraints

Comment: [MySQL docs: FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a basic example of what you are looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
 employee_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 family_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 birth_date DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(employee_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE employee_bonus (
 bonus_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 employee_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 bonus_value DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
 PRIMARY KEY(bonus_id),
 KEY fk_employee_id (employee_id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_employee_constraint FOREIGN KEY fk_employee_id(employee_id) 
    REFERENCES employees(employee_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I needed! "Foreign Key", now I know!

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia: Foreign Key

In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a referential constraint between two tables.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not a 1-to-1 relationship give the employee_bonus table its own primary key and establish a foreign key relationship between the employee table's id column and the employee_id in the employee_bonus table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid an error on insertion when attempting to add a missing employee, try this:

```
insert into employee_bonus
select ?, ?, ? -- put your insert values in here
from employee
where employee_id = ?; -- put the employee_id in here
```

This will insert one row if the employee exists and will do nothing if it doesn't.